# Placing of components in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, design-patterns, silverlight-3.0, components, z-index

I wanted a bit of advice.

I want to have a placeholder for an image (the image changes at the users will) and I want a placeholder for some other component.

Now, I have to interchange the z-index of these components so that some time the image is on the top and some other time the second component is on the top.

I am building the interface in Silverlight. This is a newbie question. Can anyone please suggest me, which component should I use as-in canvas, grid etc. that could facilitate the easy switching of the z-indices of the 2 components.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Canvas and Grid honour the Canvas.ZIndex attached property, so either will do. However a more elegant approach might be to use the Visibility property to show / hide the placeholder elements.

i.e. when you want to hide your placeholder use the following:

```
placeholder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```

This is better than using Z index in my opinion